# Symfony3 - Doctrine associated object not populating

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony-3.2

This is a basic problem where I have an associated object that I want to reference, but it's not being instantiated.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I have objects MARKET and and VENDOR associated one to many.  Markets have many vendors, vendors only have one market.  I'm looking to get the market object when I load the vendor.

```
class Vendor
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Expedient\PurchaseBundle\Entity\Market", inversedBy="vendors")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="market_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true, onDelete="SET NULL")
     */

    private $market;

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="market_id", type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $marketId;

...

/**
 * Set market
 *
 * @param \Expedient\PurchaseBundle\Entity\Market $market
 *
 * @return Market
 */
public function setMarket(\Expedient\PurchaseBundle\Entity\Market $market = null)
{
    $this->market = $market;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get market
 *
 * @return \Expedient\PurchaseBundle\Entity\Market
 */
public function getMarket()
{
    return $this->market;
}
```

When I find the Vendor object, I see there is no market set.  Note there is a marketId, but not market object is included.

```
  "vendor" => Vendor {#117 ▼
    -market: null
    -id: "11"
    -name: "A-Air Company"
    -account: ""
    -attn: "Rege Dumm / John Matthews"
    -address1: "206 Overlook Drive"
    -address2: ""
    -city: "Sewickley"
    -state: "PA"
    -zip: "15143"
    -country: "USA"
    -phone: "412-741-9420"
    -cellPhone: null
    -fax: "412-749-8590"
    -tag: "A-Air Company"
    -active: true
    -email: "rdumm@a-air.net; jmatthews@a-air.net"
    -securityAgreement: true
    -securityAgreementDate: DateTime {#114 ▶}
    -insuranceCert: true
    -insuranceCertDate: null
    -marketId: 1
  }
```

The Market class exists and has the inverse set up:

```
<?php

namespace Expedient\PurchaseBundle\Entity;

/**
 * Market
 */
class Market
{

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Vendor", mappedBy="market")
     */
    protected $vendors;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->vendors = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

Not sure where I might be going wrong with this.  I'm new to Symfony 3.

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicated `market_id` column in `Vendor`. You actually do not need `$marketId` field.

Remove `$marketId` and keep only `$market`.

WHen you want to access market ID, you can do something like:

```
$vendor->getMarket()->getId();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution that I found, seems like a specific case due to how I created the entity.

I used the reverse engineering method here to create my entities: http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html

Turns out that this does not set up the entities for associations correctly, as some of the necessary annotations were not automatically added to the Market.php class.

I had to add:

```
 * @ORM\Table(name="market")**
```

And specify the primary key:

```
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;
```

And now the **market** object related to the **vendor** is being filled.